# Pythonic way to extract elements in nested lists

Tags: python, arrays, nested-lists

I was attempting to extract elements in a list of lists using this code snippet - arr[0[0]]. It would give me the "int not subscriptable" error.

I eventually found that arr[0][0] would return the first element of the first list. But in the various SO answers I found, none gave this style as an option. (The specific problems were better addressed using list comprehension.)

Is there a reason why more experienced coders wouldn't use this to access elements within a list? Or is this a problem that's better solved using Numpy arrays, so it just doesn't come up often for standard Python 3?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `arr[0][0]`, although you might add some checks, depending on how variable your list is. The reason this is not used often is that it might be more common that one needs the first elements of _all_ the sublists, hence a list comprehension like `[x[0] for x in arr]`. `arr[0[0]]` on the other hand says `tmp = 0[0]; arr[tmp]`, which gives the exception you get.

Comment: Good answer. Thanks!